# TypeError while using navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc, mediadevices

I'm trying to substitute the deprecated `navigator.getUserMedia` with `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` but while trying I get this error:

> *TypeError: Cannot set property 'localStream' of undefined*

This is my HTML:

```
   <video ref="videoPlayer" hide.bind="screenSharing" id="videoPlayer" autoplay muted></video>
```

I'm using Aurelia Environment and my javascript is this:

```
attached() {

 if (!this.localStream) {
  this.getLocalMedia();
 }
}    

getLocalMedia() {
 let constraints: MediaStreamConstraints = {
   video: true,
   audio: true
 };

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
  .then(function (stream) {
    console.log('Got mic+video stream', stream);
    this.localStream = stream;
    this.videoPlayer.srcObject = this.localStream;
    this.videoPlayer.srcObject = stream;
   })
   .catch (function (err) {
     console.error(err);
 });
// navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, (stream) => {
//   console.log('Got mic+video stream', stream);
//   this.localStream = stream;
//   this.videoPlayer.srcObject = this.localStream;
// },
//   (err) => {
//     console.error(err);
//   }
// );

  }
```

Someone can imagine what's the problem? I'm creating an app using Electron.

I've seeen on Internet othershaving a similar problem so I printed stream:

```
Got mic+video stream 
MediaStream {id: "EIGkOQeyfsaRpweVgRG8eQiZfiuJ2HV3QZqW", active: true,     onaddtrack: null, onremovetrack: null, onactive: null…}
active: true
id: "EIGkOQeyfsaRpweVgRG8eQiZfiuJ2HV3QZqW"
onactive: null
onaddtrack: null
oninactive: null
onremovetrack: null
__proto__: MediaStream
```

I've tried also to add an EventListener when document is ready but I still have this problem; if I use the commented part with the deprecated navigator.getUserMedia everything's working

Comment: `this` is not what you think it is.

Comment: I have this at the beginning of my class, sorry I forgot:
  `export class App {
  localStream: MediaStream = null;
  videoPlayer: HTMLVideoElement;`

Comment: Are you sure your `constraints` is not `undefined` when calling `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` function?

Comment: @ymz if i print constraints i have this:
`Object audio: true video: true __proto__: Object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were using an arrow function with the old navigator.getUserMedia but are using a classic function with navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia. As [Andreas said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54531817/typeerror-while-using-navigator-mediadevices-getusermedia#comment95865296_54531817), `this` is not what you think it is, the behaviour is different between those styles.

Comment: If i change the styles in fact it works; thank you, i didn't understood what Andreas was meaning. Thank you for clarifying it